# How to use cron + python to regularly adjust screen brightness?

Tags: cron, python

I want to use cron and this script (http://askubuntu.com/questions/23593/use-webcam-to-sense-lighting-condition-and-adjust-screen-brightness):

```
import opencv
import opencv.highgui
import time
import commands


def get_image():
    image = opencv.highgui.cvQueryFrame(camera)
    return opencv.adaptors.Ipl2PIL(image)

camera = opencv.highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(-1)

while 1:
    image = get_image()
    image.thumbnail((32, 24, ))
    image = tuple(ord(i) for i in image.tostring())
    x = int((int((max(image) / 256.0) * 10) + 1) ** 0.5 / 3 * 10)
    cmd = ("sudo su -c 'echo " + str(x) +
        " > /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'")
    status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    assert status is 0
```

crontab: */30**** sudo python /home/username/screen.py

However, there are two issues:

First, can the while-loop be terminated after 5 sec or so?
Second, could anyone please try to improve the script so that lower brightness-levels can be set using the script? Maybe the way the 256 brightness-levels are mapped to the ones that can be set for the screen would need to be changed.

Thanks

Comment: Not a solution, but an alternative: have you considered f.lux? http://stereopsis.com/flux/

Comment: Yeah, I tried redshift and f.lux, both didn't work correctly. And if I use the webcam the result should be more accurate, even if the color temperature doesn't get adjusted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In older kernels there was brightness control file somewhere in `/proc`, but I think that it was the same functionality as `/sys` in your code snippet. In this `/proc`file there was several levels of brightness that you could use and probably the same is in that mechanism. Try to `cat /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` and check if there is information about brightness levels that you may use.

If you remove loop whole code will be executed once so it will be possible to set brightness only once per half hour period. There is little disadvantage of this solution - if you cover camera at the moment of brightness checking, brightness will be changed and next reading will be after half hour so you end up with completely dark screen for half hour.

To avoid this situation you could replace `while` loop by `for` loop (0 to 5 for example) with 5 seconds sleep with it. In loop you can only check brightness five times and after loop you could calculate average brightness and set it.

EDIT: Code with average from 25 seconds:

```
import opencv
import opencv.highgui
import time
import commands
from time import sleep

def get_image():
    image = opencv.highgui.cvQueryFrame(camera)
    return opencv.adaptors.Ipl2PIL(image)

camera = opencv.highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(-1)

x = []

for i in range(5):
    image = get_image()
    image.thumbnail((32, 24, ))
    image = tuple(ord(i) for i in image.tostring())
    x.append(int((int((max(image) / 256.0) * 10) + 1) ** 0.5 / 3 * 10))
    sleep(5)

sum = 0
for i in x:
    sum = sum + i

avg = sum / len(x)
cmd = ("sudo su -c 'echo " + str(avg) + " > /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'")
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
assert status is 0
```

Unfortunately I don't have option to change backlight (old kernel or something missing in kernel) and I don't have camera to check if it is working...

Comment: The output is 5. Unfortunately I don't know how to code in python, could you please try to implement that? Thx

Comment: If there is only one value I think that may be current value. In `/proc` version there was current value and a list of possible values. I edited my answer, but you must check on your own if it makes sense...

Comment: Thanks a lot, the script works great :)! I use a laptop, so covering the webcam by accident won't really be an issue. I counted the brightness levels I can adjust the screen to using the Fn keys and got 11 levels. But does that matter at all? Or would this line 
   x.append(int((int((max(image) / 256.0) * 10) + 1) ** 0.5 / 3 * 10)) need to be altered?

Comment: Could you check if there is a change in this file when you change brightness using fn? If yes whats max and min values? What is the step?

Comment: Yes, the output is: min = 0, max = 10 and the step is 1

Comment: So as the next step we could check what values are automatically assigned by this script in different conditions. What are values in file when we are in dark room? What are in bright light conditions? After that you need to modify formula in script to set 0 when there is dark and 10 when there is bright light. Unfortunately I can't help you with that because I don't have possibility to test that solution... Hint: append `print max(image)` before line with `x.append()`, run script from console, check different light conditions and map all values to 0..10.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'll have to wait until tomorrow to get accurate result for sunshine and to figure out the calculations :)

Comment: No sunshine today :(